# Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; 3 table mysql join

Tags: mysql, join

I'm getting the following error when I try to fire off a query to join 3 tables using mysql:

Error Code: **1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group     INNER JOIN `mahara.group_member` as group_members ON group_id = member' at line 6**

Mysql is:

```
SELECT `mahara.group.id` as group_id,
       `mahara.group.name` as group_name,
       `mahara.group_member.member` as member_id,
       `mahara.group_member.group` as member_groupid,
       `mahara.usr.id` as user_id
FROM `mahara.group` as group
     INNER JOIN `mahara.group_member` as group_members ON group_id = member_id,
     INNER JOIN `mahara.usr` as users ON member_id = user_id
LIMIT 0, 200;
```

For the life of me I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: could you include and post your 3 tables? your alias "group" is a reserve word... you need to use backticks when using reserved words like this: \`group\`

Comment: Also don't use reserve words. Use anything else.

Comment: @Zane He could use `anything` but not `else`. That's reserved, too ;)

Comment: @ypercube hilarious sir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few issues with your query.

First, you are attempting to create an alias using a reserved word `group`. You will have to escape the reserved word using backticks.  Also, you should have separate sets of backticks around the table and columns name, they should not be enclosed in a single pair.

Second, you have an extra comma after the join on the table `mahara.group_member` the comma after `member_id,` should be removed.

The query should be:

```
SELECT `group`.`id` as group_id,
       `group`.`name` as group_name,
       group_members.`member` as member_id,
       group_members.`group` as member_groupid,
       users.`usr.id` as user_id
FROM `mahara`.`group` as `group`
INNER JOIN `mahara`.group_member` as group_members 
  ON group_id = member_id
INNER JOIN `mahara`.`usr` as users 
  ON member_id = user_id
LIMIT 0, 200;
```

As a side, note you should avoid using [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) as names for tables, columns and aliases.

Comment: There is also an incorrect comma `,` after the first join condition (`= member_id,`) . That is invalid as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oops, I missed that one.  Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: It's also in the original query!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I updated my answer to include a note about the bad comma as well. thanks again. :)

Comment: I especially like the part where you mention not to use reserved words.